# Why is this rare belt account bound when I didn't reroll it?

Tags: diablo-iii

It just dropped and I picked it up.  I was trying to offer it to a friend but he couldn't pick it up.  I didn't reroll any of the stats on there, but its account bound.

[image: image of belt]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you get it from a Horadric Cache?

All items from a Horadric Cache appear to be account bound.

Comment: Ah that might be the case!

Comment: i just gambled a ring, it wasn't account bound so I think its the cache only that's account bound.

Comment: I just checked again and you are correct. Must have been looking at the wrong thing when I tested that last night.